# Create a JSON only after validating the form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, validation

I have a form and I'm collecting the entries of the form data and storing in my local storage. I'm able to validate the form (using jquery - `validation.min.js` plugin) and also creating a JSON.

But, I'm supposed to create JSON ONLY after validating the form with which I'm struck now.

NOTE: 
 - The validation function is in my `validation.js` file.
 - The json creation function is within my HTML between script tag.
I commented the submit handler part:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
},
```

thinking that the submit functions are colliding, but still the same result

I have a fiddle here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/spbmr2m0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this code

```
    $(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            if($('#form').valid()){
                   $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
                   return false;
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

its display JSON form value because form submit event fired event validation throws error
on submit event check for validation before prining JSON

```
if($('form').valid()){ 
  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));    
}else{
 return false;
}
```